# Publicly sharing information obtained over e-mail (no NDA)

Tags: copyright, email, competition

For data analysis purposes, I would like to request an offer / overview of product features with various companies, posing as a prospecting customer over e-mail.
I would like to analyse this data and publish it as part of a market study.

Since I would sign no NDA, and they would voluntarily provide me with the data, am I facing any restrictions what I can do with said data? In other words, can information obtained over e-mail be shared publicly without explicit approval of the sender?

Some potential legal hurdles I'd like to get your take on - ethics aside:

1. **Copyright claims**: I believe this would only apply on creative works and not just anything a company fabricates, e.g. a quote or documentation of their service
2. **Anti-competitor laws**: while the report isn't explicitly aimed at competitors of these companies, I cannot avoid that they may discover it and use the insights in a competitive context. Not sure if that is my responsibility at that point

I would put a disclaimer in the e-mail that any responses and their attachments may be shared with third parties.

Thank you for your input!

Answer (score -1):

> am I facing any restrictions what I can do with said data?

It largely depends on the data at issue, which your description does not specify.

A replier might not even be authorized to disclose information available to him. In some scenarios also you would be precluded from publishing information that wrongfully was sent to you. Case in point: It would be wrong for a replier to disclose confidential data about protected witnesses. His breach of confidentiality does not entitle you to publicly share that information.

A *clear and conspicuous* disclaimer in your e-mail request would bar a replier's copyright claims. That is because disclosures by the replier despite his awareness that you will likely share the information amounts to replier's waiver of copyright protections.

The rationale is similar in regard to anti-competitor issues. Unless your disclaimer or message represents otherwise, it would be unreasonable for a replier to rule out the possibility that a competitor might gain access to the information disclosed.

Comment: "*A clear and conspicuous disclaimer in your e-mail request would bar a replier's copyright claims.*" Citation please.

Comment: @DavidSiegel "*Citation please.*" To the extent that writing a clear and conspicuous disclaimer makes the copyright owner aware of the OP's intent, this should be obvious from the basic legal principles applicable to contracts and agreements. Regardless, see [*Effects Assoc., Inc. v. Cohen* 908 F.2d 555, 558 (1990)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/19901463908f2d55511355) ("*The leading treatise on copyright law states that a nonexclusive license [...] may even be implied from conduct.*", internal brackets and quot. marks removed).

Comment: Downvoted because ... (???)